# RAD Studio 10.3.3 Welcome Page uses Internet Explorer instead of the configured default browser

Tags: delphi

Clicking on links from Outlook etc. opens the configured default browser (Google Chrome in this case) but Delphi 10.3.3 (and 10.3.2 ...) always opens Internet Explorer when clicking on the You Tube Video Channel, which will become a problem soon since You Tube reports 'We'll stop supporting this browser soon.'.

I have not found any configuration options within the IDE to control the Welcome screen/ Is there a way to stop it using Internet Explorer? [Windows 10 & Windows 7]

Comment: This has been reported in Embarcadero's Jira system: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27845

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation and link. I have posted a comment there re the You Tube warning now being reported.

Comment: I would guess this is due the fact that RAD Studio IDE is using TWebBrowser component for displaying its welcome page. So naturally since it is based on IE any content that is to be opened in a new window is opened in IE.
Upcoming RAD Studio 10.3.4 is adding new TWebBrowser component that supports Microsoft Edge so it is possible that embarcadero will also update Welcome page part of IDE so it will no longer be based on old IE.

Comment: I am using RAD Studio 10.4 (community edition) and it still tries to open Internet Explorer, which on my Windows 10 system results in Microsoft trying to install Edge (which is already installed).

Comment: I believe the earlier comments are correct. RAD Studio provides a Web Browser capability which it itself uses on the Welcome Page. Prior to RAD Studio 11 this was based on Internet Explorer. Later versions of RAD Studio's Web Browser are based on Edge. Unfortunately, as far as I am aware, Embarcadero have still not released a Community Edition of RAD Studio 11.